# How can I iterate over .ini file and load key/values into a std::map

Tags: c++, stl, config, stdmap, std

So, currently I'm loading saved keybinds through a .ini file, but by doing so I have to initialize them to local variables on startup (better than the very verbose syntax of reading them from the file when needed), and this just leaves me with a bunch of lines that look like this:

```
Keybind_something = std::stoi(iniUtil.ReadString("Keybinds", "something", 0, 16));
```

The '16' at the end there just specifies that I'm loading a hex value '0x04' for example.

However, this leaves me with like 20 lines like this, one for each keybind.

How can I just iterate over the .ini and throw they "Keybinds" section of the .ini into a std::map called "Keybinds", with each key being the key in the .ini, and each value being the value of the key in the .ini?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve], basically something concrete enough to say anything constructive

Comment: There's noting in the C++ standard library for enumerating, or otherwise handling, .ini files. See what's available from your `iniUtil`, whatever that might be.